# Don't know what this means Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT(code=EXC_1386_BPT,subcode=0x0)

Tags: ios, swift

So as soon as I start up the app it give me this error
`0x106f499c2:  nopw   %cs:(%rax,%rax)         Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT(code=EXC_1386_BPT,subcode=0x0)`.
The debugger only says `lldb`. I don't know what this means or what to do, so if someone could help that would be great

Comment: @codester can you put that as an asnwer

Comment: NEW QUESTION! I got the first one solved. BIG THANKS to codester for that. READ THE NEW QUESTION, PLEASE!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error because of `storyboard` key.

**Go to Storyboard -> right Click on yellow button(which is your view controller) in storyboard -> there should be `jabbTableViewRefresh` -> click on cross -> clean and compile the code**

Comment: Then i get the error Thread 1:EXC_BREAKPOINT(code=EXC_1386_BPT,subcode=0x0) the console says (llbd)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@IBAction func refreshTableViewButton() {

  loadData()

}
```

per the comment, you need to wire up the button.  In storyboard command-click on your button and drag the blue line to this action.  Make sure you show the assistant editor.

Another way you can get that error is having too many referencing outlets from your button.  Check in the Connections Editor in the Utilities Pane that you have no extra outlets/actions that are unneeded.

Comment: That didn't work. Read the Question I edited it to help you help me.

Comment: Make sure you wire up the button too.

Comment: updated my answer.  If still having issues, place your project on github, I will modify it and create a branch for you