# Invisible breakpoint in Xcode

Tags: ios, breakpoints, xcode6.1, invisible

Xcode 6 have some strange break point issue. I have removed all break points from my project but still its hitting some invisible break point every time.

I have tried below things.

```
Commad + 7 and delete all break points.

(lldb) br delete
error: No breakpoints exist to be deleted.
```

I don't see any break point but still its hitting some break point. see below screenshots for reference.

[image: Invisible break point]

..Nitin

Comment: This probably means you have an error when your app loads. I'd look through your AppDelegate again to make sure you're not running into a type casting issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a breakpoint, but rather an exception in the view controller (whose name you've partially redacted here). Click on that second item in the stack trace, and it will like show you the offending line. Just go up the stack trace until you get to your own code.

It's hard to tell on the basis of so little information, but looking at the stack trace, the assembly code shown, and the exception, it looks like you've encountered a problem during a segue where a cast failed. Perhaps have a `prepareForSegue` method that is trying to cast `segue.destinationViewController` to a particular view controller class in order to pass some data to the destination, but the cast failed for some reason. Perhaps you neglected to set the base class for the destination scene in the storyboard.

But if you click on that second line in your stack trace (right below the currently highlighted line) and you'll probably be taken directly to the offending line of code.

Comment: Add on: 

You might be casting the navigation to a CustomViewController to pass some data as @Rob said. You should probably need to look at your storyboard if you have a navigation inbetween your DestinationViewController and your SourceViewController.

Answer (score 1):

There don't have to be any breakpoints set in you project to encounter this kind of behaviour. It means that the thread was aborted because of a fatal error. You just can't see the code, because it happened somewhere deeper in the system, so the Xcode only shows you the assembly code.

As I can see from your stack trace, these threads could be related to your question:

[swift prepareForSegue not working / exc_breakpoint (code=exc_i386_bpt subcode=0x0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27613637/swift-prepareforsegue-not-working-exc-breakpoint-code-exc-i386-bpt-subcode-0x)

[Don't know what this means Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT(code=EXC_1386_BPT,subcode=0x0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26195827/dont-know-what-this-means-thread-1-exc-breakpointcode-exc-1386-bpt-subcode-0x)